# Angular 2+ and storing data in variable from http in service

Tags: angular

I have getPrivateLesson() in my service, that returns the array of objects. How to run that function in service (once, on initialization) and store returned data in variable filteredPrivateLessons? I tried with subject and constructor but without positive effect.

```
@Injectable()
export class PrivateLessonsService {

  private _privateLessonsUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/lessons";
  public filteredPrivateLessons: PrivateLesson[];
  public filteredPrivateLessonsUpdate = new EventEmitter<PrivateLesson[]>();

  private privateLessonsSubject = new Subject<any>()
  public privateLessonsChange$ = this.privateLessonsSubject.asObservable();


  constructor(private _http: Http,  private _httpClient: HttpClient) {

    this.privateLessonsChange$.subscribe(response => {
      this.filteredPrivateLessons = this.getPrivateLessons();
    });

  }

  getPrivateLessons() : any {
    return this._http.get(this._privateLessonsUrl)
      .map( (response: Response) => response.json() );    
  }

  getFilteredPrivateLessons() {
    return this.filteredPrivateLessons;
  }
  setFilteredPrivateLessons(privateLessons: PrivateLesson[]) {
    this.filteredPrivateLessons = privateLessons;
    this.filteredPrivateLessonsUpdate.emit(this.filteredPrivateLessons);
  }

}
```

Comment: you should pass filteredPrivateLessons to next  this.filteredPrivateLessonsUpdate.next(this.filteredprivateLessons)

Comment: Okay, I added that line in constructor as last line, but it does not affect.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject this service in you app.component and call the function like so:

app.component.ts :

```
    ngOnInit(){
        this._privateLessonsService.getPrivateLessons().subscribe(
        success =>{
          this._privateLessonsService.filteredPrivateLessons = success;
        },
        error =>{
          //Handle error here
        }
      );
    }
```

You can then assume in the rest of your app that the array is ready and stored within your service object. Where you need to read it, inject the service and you will have access to it like so :

```
this._privateLessonsService.filteredPrivateLessons
```

No Need for a subject here as you don't need to perform an action following the change of that array. You only need to download it once and have access to it!

Comment: be careful that you don't inject the service twice or more times, otherwise, you will have different contexts and different variables in the services.

Comment: This will only happen if you inject the same service in 2 different Modules. you can inject the service within the same module any number of times and access the same data everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Per comments from @Rahul Gupta editing the answer.

@OP- If you are not able to assign the response value to the variable, you can try adding an anonymous function to use this asynchronously.

I am not sure how do you want to use this on your component but now your variable should have the response value. Another way could be to move subscriber to your component(though i am not sure how your requirement is)

Editing my earlier response to add anon function.

```
this.getPrivateLessons().subscribe(response => {
      this.filteredPrivateLessons = res;
   },
   () => {
        console.log(this.filteredPrivateLessons);
    });
}

getPrivateLessons() : any {
   return this._http.get(this._privateLessonsUrl)
      .map( (response: Response) => response.json() );    
}
```

Comment: when i put console.log(response), it shows result correctly in console, but I dont see changes elsewhere...

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: @lampkawtubce, I would suggest to try my edited code and you should be able to use the variable with a defined response value.

Comment: @RahulGupta, +1 for your comment